# Scrape / extract data from hidden divs in scrapy

Tags: javascript, html, scrapy

Hi I am trying to scrape a website where there is an input text. Whenever, I click on the input text there are dropdown suggestions for the value of the input text. It is not on select tag.

The value of those suggestion is inside a div tag elements. There were almost 200 divs/suggestions of it.

What I did is scrape from it using scrapy using xpath / css selectors. I found out that these 200 divs are actually hidden when I view the code using "View page source" instead of "Inspect elements".

Please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

These elements are generated on the fly by some dropdown library, so you have to investigate the website source code and/or the HTTP requests it's making. All the data you are looking for should be there (most likely in JSON format), not in the HTML itself.

For example, if you are using Chrome:

1. Press `F12` to open devtools while you are on the website
2. Press `F5` to reload the page
3. Navigate to `Network` or `Source` tab
4. Try to locate the data (`CTRL+F` would be really helpful here)